# Emacs can not be closed, because it cannot save customizations

Tags: windows-7, emacs, bookmarks

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Cannot save customizations; init
>   file was not fully loaded")   signal(error ("Cannot save
>   customizations; init file was not fully loaded"))   error("Cannot save
>   customizations; init file was not fully loaded")   custom-save-all()
>   customize-save-variable(bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file
>   "~\.emacs.d\bookmarks")   bookmark-save()
>   bookmark-exit-hook-internal()   kill-emacs()
>   save-buffers-kill-emacs()   handle-delete-frame((delete-frame (#)))

since one day I'm having this problem here with emacs:
I cant not end it because of the error message above.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Emacs version GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) on Windows 7

I did not change anything intentionally, maybe this has to do with a Windows Update or some changes in our network structure? The .emacs file is saved in my home directory which is store in my Windows-7 user profile (and therefore somehow synced with our server).

Comment: First verify the Emacs installation works without the `.emacs` file -- e.g., by renaming it and restarting and quitting Emacs.  If the Emacs application loads correctly without the `.emacs` file, then put it back the way it was and proceed to bisect issue - first comment out the second half of `.emacs`. If the problem is gone, that means it was in the second half, if not - it's in the first half. Continue until you find the line with the error.  You may find that the issue is traceable to another library . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for your trouble.  You ran into a [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) bug.

Try evaluating this code, to redefine this function:

```
(defun bookmark-exit-hook-internal ()   ; This goes on `kill-emacs-hook'.
  "Save currently defined bookmarks and perhaps bookmark menu-list state.
Run `bookmark-exit-hook', then save bookmarks if they were updated.
Then save menu-list state to file `bmkp-bmenu-state-file', but only if
that option is non-nil."
  (run-hooks 'bookmark-exit-hook)
  (when (bookmark-time-to-save-p t)
    (condition-case err ; Do NOT raise error.  (Need to be able to exit.)
        (bookmark-save)
      (error (if (fboundp 'display-warning)
                 (display-warning 'bookmark-plus (error-message-string err))
               (message (error-message-string err))
               (sit-for 4))
             nil)))
  (bmkp-save-menu-list-state))
```

I have updated source file [`bookmark+-1.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/bookmark%2b-1.el) with that definition now.  It should take care of the problem -- that is, it should show you the error message but let you exit Emacs.

If this change does not fix the problem, please follow up with me by email, and I will get it fixed.

The problem was that the **Bookmark+** version of `bookmark-save` saves the updated value of option `bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file` to your custom file (or init file), and this was impossible because your init file was not successfully loaded, for some reason.

Again, sorry for your trouble.  *Before doing any of the above* in order to exit Emacs, *make a copy of your bookmarks file*, just to be safe.

Other than the above, you apparently have a problem in your init file (`~/.emacs`).  @lawlist mentioned in a comment how to attack that: divide and conquer, aka recursively bisect your init file to narrow down the location of the problem.

And next time you see "bookmark" or `bmkp-` (the **Bookmark** prefix) in a backtrace or an error message, let me know about your problem as soon as possible. ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed reply and for your help! I'll try that as soon as I'm again at the computer with this problem (next week). If I understand correctly, the proper cause of my problem is that the `.emacs` file was not successfully loaded, so I'll have to search for the root cause...

Comment: Yes, do a binary search on your init file to find what part is flaky. I use command `comment-region` to comment and uncomment (with `C-u`) sections of text, to do that. But download the latest `bookmark+-1.el` anyway, go (hopefully) prevent the inability to exit.

Comment: thanks a lot - at least that solves the symptomes, now I have to go searching for the root cause.